# Jetty debug mode

Tags: debugging, jetty

I have a webapp that I launch on a jetty version 7.5.1 with runjettyrun 1.3.3. It works fine. But when I try to launch jetty in debug mode I got these errors sack trace in eclipse :

```
livraison (2) [Jetty Webapp]    
    runjettyrun.Bootstrap at localhost:60282    
        Thread [main] (Suspended (exception ClassNotFoundException))    
            owns: Object  (id=23)   
            owns: Object  (id=24)   
            URLClassLoader$1.run() line: not available [local variables unavailable]    
            URLClassLoader$1.run() line: not available  
            AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>, AccessControlContext) line: not available [native method]   
            Launcher$ExtClassLoader(URLClassLoader).findClass(String) line: not available   
            Launcher$ExtClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available 
            Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available 
            Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available  
            Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String) line: not available  
            LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(boolean, int, String) line: not available   
    C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe (22 août 2014 14:36:09)
```

It says there is a ClassNotFoundException but doesn't say what one. How could I found it ?

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` is not a fatal error for run-jetty-run, skip it, ignore it, move on. (its just trying to discover what your configuration / environment has available)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running debug mode via environment variables than from eclipse.